# Implement redirect for domain from Namecheap's domain control panel

Tags: redirects, dns, namecheap

I have two domains, I want one domain to redirect all URLs to another domain. How do I do it in the Namecheap control panel?.

Does setting up redirect in domain control panel means users can visit the new domain directly without going onto the server? I can set up `.htaccess` redirect in the server that hosts the old domain, but I don't want users to visit the old server then, get redirected to new server.

I have set `URL Redirect` with `host` as `@` and value as `ww1.newdomain.com` , and `URL Redirect` with `host` as `*` and value as `ww1.newdomain.com` . Will the user be redirected when accessing `olddomain.com/products/` , to `ww1.newdomain.com/products/` ??

Comment: Is your concern of not visiting your server one of cost?  Do you want to remove that hosting?  Or is there some other reason that you don't want to use `.htaccess` from your hosting account.

Comment: I don't want to have load on that server, and I read that using domain control panel to redirect domains can make google reindex that newly moved site faster.

Comment: Redirects typically put very little load on a server.  Using your own server with `.htaccess` would allow you to redirect HTTPS requests whereas Namecheaps domain panel redirects are very unlikely to get a security certificate for the redirected domain.  If you had a site on your old domain that used HTTPS, you are going to need a redirect that supports HTTPS.

Comment: As long as the domain is redirected properly, Google isn't going to know how the redirects are implemented. The site will get moved over just as quickly either way.  If Google indexed your old domain with HTTPS, you absolutely need to be able to maintain a security certificate for the old domain and redirect HTTPS URLs from it for SEO.

Comment: Still., I would be happy if I set the URL redirects in the domain control panel. Thank you for the help.